# Audio won't work after latest update [Windows Version 10.0.15063]

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card, windows-10-v1703

I'm using a [Sound Blaster Z](http://se.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-z) card to power my [DT 990 PRO *(250ohm)*](http://europe.beyerdynamic.com/shop/dt-990-pro.html) headphones, which works just fine. 
But after receiving windows update [10.0.15063](https://changewindows.org/build/15063/pc) the audio stopped working. 
I've tried to figure out where the problem lies, and as it stands windows thinks that everything is fine, there are no driver errors in the device manager, and windows still uses the [Sound Blaster Z Speaker playback device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crnmq.png).

Lastly I've tried updating the sound card drivers but that didn't help.

Any ideas why this is happening? Or any ideas how to revert it / fix it?

Comment: Strange, as I had similar issues with my X-Fi HD when upgrading to the Anniversary Update and I really just needed to update the drivers. My procedure was to firstly completely uninstall all drivers and software of the sound card, then [download the new driver from Creative](http://support.creative.com/downloads/welcome.aspx?nLanguageLocale=1033&nOS=52&nDriverType=1#type_1), restart and then install the newly downloaded driver. If that doesn't help then I'd try the procedure again but without forced driver signature.
Have you tried it like this? Or did you "just" click on `Update drivers`?

Comment: @flolilolilo I haven't tried it like that, i just clicked `Update drivers`. But I'll give it a go. I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: @flolilolilo That worked! Thank you very much! Any idea why? (also, post your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit)

Comment: Done - also "answered" (TL; DR: I have no idea) the question as to why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues with my Creative X-Fi HD when upgrading to the Anniversary Update. My procedure was:

1. Completely uninstall all drivers and software of the sound card,
2. Download the new driver (and software, if wanted) from [Creative](http://support.creative.com/downloads/welcome.aspx?nLanguageLocale=1033&nOS=52&nDriverType=1#type_1),
3. Restart,
4. Install new driver (and software)

If that doesn't help then I'd try the procedure again but without forced driver signature (as some manufacturers seem to have problems with it):

1. In Start-Menu, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on "Restart",
2. Click on "Troubleshoot"
3. Click on "Advanced Options"
4. Click on "Startup Settings"
5. Restart, and in the next window, hit <kbd>F7</kbd>.
6. Repeat driver-update-procedure.

As to why that is: I have no proper idea. Perhaps the Creator's/Anniversary Update changed some APIs that the driver would need, or perhaps the old driver itself had some sort of problem in identifying the new version of Windows (I'm thinking of some kind of compatibility-check gone wrong). Creative itself only states in the latest update for your card:

> Bug fixes and general improvements for Windows® 10

Whereas on my driver, they state:

> General driver optimization

That's not a very helpful changelog, and therefore I fear we're left with wild guesses. But what I can say is that it's always a good idea to completely re-install drivers in Windows, as the update-feature doesn't prove to be too helpful most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and after update Windows 10, version 10.0.15063 my PC had no AUDIO. My PC is SONY Vaio model VPCEB44EG.I did the following and the AUDIO came back.

The first thing to do is go to the Sound panel and verify that "Speakers" are set as default audio playback device. If that is OK, "refresh" the sound by going to the Device manager, uninstall the sound (e.g. Realtek or whatever you have as sound hardware) **DO NOT uninstall the drivers**, then restart the PC and when Windows starts it will detect and reinstall the sound.

Ref:https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/65021-sound-does-not-work-after-latest-win-10-update.html

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> while booting and select "Boot in Safe Mode". 
Try troubleshooting the audio device. 
It worked for me in my Dell PC.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but it might be prudent to avoid submitting answers in all-caps.  On a more technical note, you actually can't boot into Safe Mode on a Windows 10 machine by pressing F8:  [Boot into Safe Mode on Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2304-boot-into-safe-mode-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'm new as you guessed but F8 works fine in my windows 10.